# I'd like to retrieve images from phpMyAdmin database and display them on an HTML table

Tags: php, html, database, phpmyadmin

The images are stored as a BLOB type in my database. I want the user to be able to click on a 'View Inventory' button and be taken to a page with an HTML table that displays images for each item.

This is the table in my php file:

```
echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Categor</th>";
            echo "<th>Description</th>";
            echo "<th>Unit Cost</th>";
            echo "<th>XS Quantity</th>";
            echo "<th>S Quantity</th>";
            echo "<th>M Quantity</th>";
            echo "<th>L Quantity</th>";
            echo "<th>XL Quantity</th>";
            echo "<th>XXL Quantity</th>";
            echo "<th>XXXL Quantity</th>";
            echo "<th>Image</th>";
            echo "<th></th>";
        echo "</tr>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>{$row['category']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['description']}</td>";
            echo "<td>$ {$row['unitCost']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['xsQuantity']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['sQuantity']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['mQuantity']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['lQuantity']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['xlQuantity']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['xxlQuantity']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['xxxlQuantity']}</td>";
            echo "<td><img src='Downloads/".$row['apparelImage']."'></td>";
            echo "<td><a href='#'>Add</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: You need to edit your post so that it is a question.  The question should  be of the form:  "1) this is what I do 2) this is the result I get 3) this is the result I want ... what have I done wrong?"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Martin!

Comment: phpMyAdmin is not a database, it is a database **client**

Answer (score 0):

If your image is stored as blob, you can't do `echo "<td><img src='Downloads/".$row['apparelImage']."'></td>";`

You should print a `img` tag which will handling your image. Pass row ID in `src` attribute of this tag and get it in script. Then, get the record from database and set headers to show image.

Like:

```
echo '<img src="script_to_show_image.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">';
```

In `script_to_show_image.php`, after get record from database, you must set headers to print image correctly:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
```

Then, print the content:

```
echo $apparelImage;
```

Comment: My image is stored as a VARCHAR. Regarding your script_to_show_image.php advice, I'm not sure what the best way to do this would be.

Comment: <?php
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $apparelImage = $row['apparelImage'];
  }
 
  header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
 ?>                                                                                                                        This is what I have so far for script_to_show_image.php

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out!

Comment: Ok. If it works for you, mark the response as answer. ;-)